# How to get a MultipartHttpServletRequest from RequestContextHolder?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I have configured the access decision manager to check a request before being processed by the servlet the key line is:-

```
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getRequest();
```

All good. However when the request is `enctype="multipart/form-data"` how do I get hold of the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` when `RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getRequest()` only returns `HttpServletRequest`?

I am using spring 2.5.

Answer (score 2):

`MultipartHttpServletRequest` is n Spring-specific interface for handling multipart form submissions. The default implementation is `DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest`, which has a constructor that takes a `HttpServletRequest`.

So:

```
HttpServletRequest originalRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest();
MultipartHttpServletRequest multiPartRequest = new DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest(originalRequest);
```

Comment: Hia Skaffman. Thanks for the reply. I'm using Spring 2.5 I don't have the RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes().getRequest(); method.

Comment: @user456147: I copied that from your question :)  Anyway, see my edit.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from having

```
<form method=<method> action=<url> enctype="multipart/form-data"></form>
```

you have to have

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

in your spring configuration file.

Here is nice tutorial on the same

http://techdive.in/spring/spring-file-upload

Answer (score 0):

If you are using spring-mvc, make sure you put this line

```
<bean id="multipartResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

in your app-config.xml.

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest from RequestContextHolder.
DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest really implements HttpServletRequest.
But there're 2 request instances if you use CommonsMultipartResolver. One is DefaultMultipartHttpServletRequest instance, and another is HttpServletRequest instance.
Actually I don't know how to get the first instance from RequestContextHolder. You can get the second instance from it.