# Create MultipartHttpServletRequest then getting Exception

Tags: java, spring

When creating MultipartHttpServletRequest then getting Exception.
I have created HttpServletRequest but when casting with MultipartHttpServletRequest  then getting Exception
My code is

```
public void uploadFileOnLocal(@RequestParam Long caseId, HttpServletRequest request ,HttpServletResponse response) {

MultipartHttpServletRequest multipartRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
```

Exception is :

```
   SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [download] in context with path   [/localdownload] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is           java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest] with root cause
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade cannot be cast to org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartHttpServletRequest
at com.triventkiosk.controller.DownloadController.uploadFileOnLocal(DownloadController.java:98)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:137)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:776)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:705)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:537)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to have

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

Comment: @Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
  public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
Thanks for ans..we can try with below too 
final CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE);
    return multipartResolver;
  }

Answer (score 3):

Your tag in JSP may not have enctype="multipart/form-data" as property , make form tag as , and this error will be removed. e.g. :

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
</form>
```

Depending in your Spring version you may have to cast it properly - Do check this thread [How to get a MultipartHttpServletRequest from RequestContextHolder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6628510/how-to-get-a-multiparthttpservletrequest-from-requestcontextholder)

Comment: My jsp code is <form action="${fileUploadOnPath}fileLocalUpload.htm?method="post"
                        enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 0):

```
@Bean(name = "multipartResolver")
public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
  final CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new 
  CommonsMultipartResolver();
  multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE);
  return multipartResolver;
}
private static final long MAX_FILE_UPLOAD_SIZE = 1024L * 1024L * 4L;
```